# nginx won't match server_name for subdomain

Tags: nginx

I can't get nginx to match a server declaration for a subdomain.
I'm using [linuxserver/letsencrypt](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-letsencrypt), a docker which requests ssl certs from the letsencrypt api, and contains a basic nginx configuration.

The domain structure is sub1.host.example.com

My configuration has a default_server, and one subdomain configured with server_name 'sub1.*'

Any requests to sub1.host.example.com are routed through the default-server configuration, I'm using the log output to confirm.

My server configuration is below.

```
  log_format sub 'shout $host $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                 '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                 '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
    log_format def 'default-server $host $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
               '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
               '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

# main server block
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;

    root /config/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name _;

    access_log /config/log/nginx/access.log def;


    # all ssl related config moved to ssl.conf
    include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php?$args =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # With php7-cgi alone:
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php7-fpm:
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

}

# sample reverse proxy config without url base, but as a subdomain "cp", ip and port same as above
# notice this is a new server block, you need a new server block for each subdomain
#server {
#   listen 443 ssl;
#
#   root /config/www;
#   index index.html index.htm index.php;
#
#   server_name cp.*;
#
#   include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;
#
#   client_max_body_size 0;
#
#   location / {
#       auth_basic "Restricted";
#       auth_basic_user_file /config/nginx/.htpasswd;
#       include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
#       proxy_pass http://192.168.1.50:5050;    
#   }
#}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  root /config/www;
  index index.html index.htm index.php
  server_name sub1.*;
  include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;
  client_max_body_size 0;

  access_log /config/log/nginx/access.log sub;

  location / {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /config/nginx/.htpasswd;
    include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
  }
}
```

I've tried / reviewed a bunch of things which may or may not be relevant:

*upstream*

my config is pretty much identical to the example provided by the docker container, I've omitted some of the comments which aren't relevant, [original is here](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-letsencrypt/blob/master/root/defaults/default)

There *is* an issue on that repo about someone's subdomains not matching, but that user said it was a problem with their redirect configuration, with redirects being issued to an IP address, so not relevant to this.

So I'm pretty sure this is a general nginx misconfiguration on my part rather than an issue with that repo.

*logging requests*

in my config you'll see I've used a custom format to ensure that the host is correct, and which server is responding. All requests to 'sub1.host.example.com' generate a line in access log like this:

```
default-server sub1.host.example.com 120.146.246.49 - - [31/Mar/2018:15:40:39 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0"
```

*DNS Configuration*

I've not configured a separate dns zone for host.example.com, so in the zone for example.com I have an 'A' record for 'sub1.host' which points to the IP address for the host running nginx. This is resolved correctly. Also, running 'hostname -f' returns 'host.example.com'

*letsencrypt certs*

This all seems to be working correctly, pages returned by the default-server have valid certs. I don't think anything there is interfering with this server.

*nginx name resolution*

The server-name for the default-server is '_' which is apparently a purposely invalid hostname. I've reviewed the nginx name resolution order, nothing seems really relevant to the issue at hand.

*no wildcards*

I tried `server_name sub1.host.example.com;`, which didn't work.

Comment: It's default_server not default-server. Try putting in the actual domain name without wildcards to see if it works. I'd like to see logs. Your question is also quite wordy. Please edit your question for clarity.

Comment: Sure, my first time posting a question sorry. I did try a fqdn without wildcards. My question did include the access log (sans 100 more lines the same), nothing in error log. Is there anything unclear in my question? Or do you just want me to delete the wordy later portion?

Comment: You are missing a trailing `;` from the line before the `server_name` directive.

Comment: @RichardSmith ah yes, that would do it. Thanks very much!